# TightVNC and Ubuntu 18.04 desktop not working properly

Tags: ubuntu, vnc

I have a home server running Ubuntu Desktop 18.04. I'm trying to get the full Gnome desktop using TightVNC in a headless configuration. I can't quite seem to find the correct arguments for the Xvnc-session file.

This is my current session file:

```
#!/bin/sh
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME-Flashback:Unity"
export XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-flashback-"
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
gnome-panel &
unity-settings-daemon &
gnome-flashback &
metacity &
nautilus &
```

Using this I get a single window but without the desktop as shown below.
[VNC Client View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VTbl.jpg)

What arguments am I missing in the session file to get the full desktop in Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 0):

I followed instruction https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-ubuntu-18-04-vnc-grey-screen/
It has resolved my issue with vnc gray screen.

```
sudo apt install gnome-session-flashback
```

Then change the `~/.vnc/xstartup`

```
 #!/bin/sh
 autocutsel -fork
 xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
 xsetroot -solid grey
 export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
 export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME-Flashback:Unity"
 export XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-flashback-"
 unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
 gnome-session --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check --debug &
```

In order to get desktop GUI experience you can also use XRDP
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-18-04/